# Axure - url parameter for logic?

Tags: axure

I'd like to have a parameter in the Axure prototype URL, like "http://share.axure.com/Foo/homepage.html?state=guest" which will set an Axure variable "state" to "guest", for example.

(Right now, I have a navigation page (preceding the "homepage") load by default where where the user selects one of several links that opens the "homepage" with the "state" variable set.)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: quite late to answer this but have a look on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this will help you

You want to open a particular state of the dynamic panel according the variable you passed on it.You can do this in axure using **GLOBAL VARIABLE**

First click on it.

[image]

This will lead you to this pop up.

[image]

and on your **onload** event you can open any state according to your condition(if/else).

Comment: To get a unique URL you can create a separate page where you set the Global Variable with the onLoad event. Then autoforward to your target page using Open Link

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Anurag Bhakuni answered and give an updated response, in Axure RP 8, you can set global variables on interactions. (*If you're familiar with jQuery, Axure's interactions are like jQuery events*).

Create an object - in your case a text link. Select the link and head over to the Inspector pane and click the **PROPERTIES** tab. This will open the **Case Editor**.

Double-click the interaction you want to use, in this case **OnClick**.

In the left column, you have a list of actions to choose from. Select **Set Variable Value** and then click **Add variable**.

[Set Variable Value and Add variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zTte.png)

Give the new variable a new name. I used **State**. When a user clicks on the text link, this variable will be set to **guest**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfbWR.png)

Now, on subsequent pages, you can use this variable with conditional statements. Once again in the **Case Editor**, you can click **Add Condition** at the top of the dialogue box.

- Select *value of variable* in the first dropdown
- Select *State* in the second dropdown
- Write "guest" in the input box

This says, "If the value of State equals "guest"...

...do something. Select an action from the left column to tell it what to do if this condition is met.